# How to get back to index.html in .htaccess?

Tags: html, .htaccess, cpanel

I am completely new writing in .htaccess format. First what I did was add this in for the removal of my .html extensions. I am doing all this in cPanel under the /public_html/ folder. I also moved my .htaccess file inside that folder.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

All my pages that I have up right now are working without the extensions, expect when I go back to my homepage. Originally index.html but now when I click the home button my url looks like http://allisonshtml.com/public_html

Really to me when I think about this, its kind of backwards because my website is inside the public_html folder.

I tried everything in my power to fix this. Please help or any feedback would be lovely!

Comment: have you tried simply renaming the htaccess file to see if that resolves the issue? it doesnt look to me like the problem is in this file though. if it doesnt solve it then look into the code of the file where you clicked home. you might find the href for the link in that file is wrong.

Comment: I have tried changing the href to index.html, index nothing seems to work. It all goes back to website.com/public_html

Comment: rename to .htaccess-old and see if that changes things.

Comment: second condition is missing a \ should be RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f

Comment: nope, it just make everything not show then.

Comment: oh yes, for some reason it didnt show on here but I had that \ added already

Comment: It worked before changing htaccess and removing it doesnt solve it?

Comment: no it didn't, pretty much my index link is opening the /public_html/ folder, so is it currently in the root directory? I just don't understand this

Comment: can you edit your answer and show the code for the links please. public_html is the webroot yes. htaccess should be in that folder normally.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, my Google chrome wasn't rendering. Cleared the background data and waaalaa it worked.